# Geometric connection between Dini derivative and scalar products

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, vectors

I am reading through a [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/912339) (Sec. 4.5) that uses a geometric construction not quite clear to me.

Namely, let $B$ be a closed ball in $\mathbb R^n$ centered at $x$.
Let $s \in B$.
Next, let $w$ be an arbitrary vector.
Then, for a sufficiently small $\varepsilon > 0$, there is $z \in \partial B$ such that

$$ z - (s + \varepsilon w) $$

is parallel to $x-s$ and pointing in the same direction.

That is,

$$
\Biggl\langle z - (s + \varepsilon w), \frac{x-s}{\| x - s \|} \Biggr\rangle = \| z - (s + \varepsilon w) \|
$$

While I understand that such a $z$ can be found, **I fail to see why**

$$
\Biggl\langle z - s, \frac{x-s}{\| x - s \|} \Biggr\rangle = \mathcal O(\varepsilon^2)
$$

The paper then claims that

$$
- \varepsilon \Biggl\langle w, \frac{x-s}{\| x - s \|} \Biggr\rangle = \| z - (s + \varepsilon w) \| + \mathcal O(\varepsilon^2)
$$

which clearly uses the above statement.

I can visualize how to find $z$ so that $z - (s + \varepsilon w)$ and $x-s$ are parallel.
But $\varepsilon$ is small so that the direction of the vector $s$ is barely changed.
Then, it seems $z-s$ is almost parallel to $x-s$.

**Why should their scalar product be small?**

Comment: It's not. As you say, $\langle z - s, \frac{x-s}{\lVert x - s \rVert} \rangle = \lVert z - s \rVert + O(\epsilon)$. Maybe a typo in the paper?

Comment: @Adam see [here](https://i.postimg.cc/Kj577CBn/123.png). Definitely not a typo. I can't see what the author was even trying to show

Comment: The vectors z-s and x-s never get to the same length. In $\Bbb R^2$ you could see that points Z, S, X (X being the center of the disk) are on the same diameter line and the length of ZS (magnitude of z-s) is- at the limit between radius (when XS is zero) and diameter (when XS at limit reaches the radius).

Comment: @WindSoul why should they get to the same length?

Comment: Looking at the dot product you (and me) don’t understand why it should be $0^2$: if that was true then it  must come from $0\cdot 0$-this is where those vectors would be needed to take same length, which is prevented by the location of the points Z,X,S. At worst  it could be a “$\cdot 0$” when $S\to X$.

Comment: $|zs|=r+|xs|, r\gt 0; \frac{<zs,xs>}{|xs|}=r+|xs|\to 0^1\text{when } r\to 0; zs, xs \text { length of z-s, x-s}; r \text{ radius of the ball}$. Disregard “$S\to X$”.

Comment: I agree, there seems to be no reason for their scalar product to be small.

Comment: @joriki Have you looked into the referenced paper? I can't fathom this paper is wrong in such a simple claim

Comment: @RubiShnol: I looked at the excerpt you provided. The paper itself is behind a paywall. If there's any room for doubt, it must be in the definition of $s$ and $w$, which are not in the excerpt – if you provide another excerpt for that, I'd take another look.

Comment: @joriki Can I send you the paper somehow?

Comment: @RubiShnol: My [profile page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6622/joriki) links to my GitHub account, where my email address is public.

Comment: @joriki Thanks, I sent it to you. Although I have to say $s, w$ are independent of the proof of this particular claim, I'm pretty sure

Answer (score 1):

This would be correct if $s$ were itself in $\partial B$. The paper doesn’t say it is, but perhaps there’s a reason to assume this? Apparently $s$ is a point where $V$ is minimal in $B$ (section $4.2$, item $2$). Perhaps it can be shown that the minimum must be attained on the boundary? That’s the only thing I can think of that would make sense of this.

Comment: I very much doubt that. In other papers of this and others authors, it is never assumed that the local minimum over a ball lie on the boundary of the ball. Besides, what would it change? I can't see. I feel the problem is that you can pick such a $z$ to simultaneously satisfy the colinearity condition and make $\langle z-s, x-s \rangle$ small which could only be done via getting them close to orthogonal

Comment: Btw, I tried to fix the proof via taking $z$ anywhere in the ball, not necessarily on the boundary. Failed either

Comment: "Besides, what would it change?": If $s$ were on the boundary, then $z-s$ would be approximately orthogonal to $x-s$ (since the boundary of the ball is orthogonal to the radius), so the scalar product would indeed be $O\left(\epsilon^2\right)$.

Comment: Well, but then if $s+\varepsilon w$ points inwards (inside the ball), you would have to pick a $z$ on the completely opposite side of the sphere to make $z - (s +\varepsilon w)$ point in the same direction as $x-s$

Comment: @RubiShnol: True, in that one special case. It's at least conceivable that that case is excluded by the (to me) cryptic conditions on $w$ at the beginning of Section $4.5$.

Comment: I reread everything once again and I don't see any indication in the paper as to why $s$ has to be on the boundary, nor the $s+\varepsilon w$ has to point outward. Also, I don't see why this should be so at all. The argument in the proof of 4.5 actually doesn't need either of $s, z$ to lie on the boundary. The major problem is that the angle between $x-s$ and $s + \varepsilon w$ has to be $>\frac \pi 2$, otherwise the argument collapses. The proof overall thus seems wrong, I'm afraid